# R qqman manhattan png

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, genetics

I ran the R package 'qqman' from the CRAN Berkeley http repository. I used fread to read in the GWAS summary statistics. The output is a 33.5MB PDF file that slowly 'draws' the plot and crashes Adobe. Why is the output PDF instead of a nice and simple PNG?

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
library(data.table)   
library(qqman)  

c <- fread("path", header = TRUE, data.table=FALSE)  

manhattan(c, chr = "CHR", bp = "BP", p = "P", snp = "SNP", col = c("blue", "cyan"), 
  chrlabs = NULL, suggestiveline = -log10(1e-05), genomewideline = -log10(5e-08), 
  highlight = NULL, logp = TRUE, annotatePval = NULL, annotateTop = TRUE)
```

Comment: How many points are you trying to plot? How are you running this? Are you running with `Rscript`? Is the file generated named `Rplots.pdf`?

Comment: Yes I'm running it with Rscript but I could try CMD Batch R if you recommend. I didn't specify Rplots.pdf but I thought the source code was supposed to output a png by default.

Comment: The code will use whatever your default graphics device is. In most cases this a PDF. Rather than relying on a default, you can use explicit calls to `png()` (giving a file name, width, and height) before the call to `manhattan()` and then `dev.off()` after.

Comment: With that many points most likely it won't make any difference if you drop 80% of points, either drop all with pvalue>0.01 or drop some of them at random.

Comment: Or we can [flatten the pdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162922/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-a-pdf-image-from-the-command-line).